# Como saber quais usuários possuem uma foto em uma pasta via OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo um sistema onde as fotos são armazenadas em **pasta** e não no banco de dados. Para salvamento do arquivo da foto, o sistema utiliza a seguinte padronização:

*Nome do Usuário:* Otávio Augusto | *Chave Primária:* 12345

Nome do arquivo da foto: OTAVIO_AUGUSTO_12345.jpg

Imaginem que o caminho para as fotos é: **C:\Sistema\imagens**, desta forma, seria possível encontrar a foto deste usuário no caminho: "C:\Sistema\imagens\OTAVIO_AUGUSTO_12345.jpg".

Se minha intenção fosse apresentar exatamente esta foto em um relatório, de forma não dinâmica, utilizaria a seguinte instrução:

```
Select
    BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\SophiA\imagens\OTAVIO_AUGUSTO_13965.jpg' , SINGLE_BLOB) Load
```

Onde iria me retornar o binário para apresentação da foto.

Porém, o que preciso saber é em uma lista de usuários, quais possuem foto e quais não possuem, por exemplo:

```
Select

    PK_USUARIO,
    Case 
        When BulkColumn is not null then 'Possuí Foto'
        Else 'Não Possuí Foto'
    End AS VERIFICA_FOTO

    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\SophiA\imagens\ + NOME_USUARIO + '_' 
                                              + PK_USUARIO 
                                              +'.jpg' , SINGLE_BLOB) Load
Where 

PK_USUARIO In (12345,22222,33333)
```

E o retorno desejado seria algo como:

```
PK_USUARIO  VERIFICA_FOTO
12345       Possuí Foto
22222       Não Possuí Foto
33333       Não Possuí Foto
```

O problema é que, caso não exista a foto na pasta, ao invés de "Null", o SQL retorna um erro.

(`Mensagem 4860, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1 Não é possível carregar em massa. O arquivo "C:\Sistema\imagens\OTAVIO_AUGUSTO_13965.jpg" não existe ou você não tem direitos de acesso ao arquivo.`)

Como trabalhar esta query de forma a tratar este erro e retornar quais usuários possuem foto e quais não possuem? Caso exista ao menos um usuário que esteja sem foto, então o erro será apresentado. É possível utilizar TRY CATCH?

Desde já, agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido através da procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FOTO_USUARIO  
                   @Codigo integer,  
                   @TipoPessoa integer,  
                   @FOTO VARBINARY(max) OUTPUT  
                   AS    
                   begin  
                           DECLARE @FILE VARCHAR(100);  
                           DECLARE @nome_usuario VARCHAR(100);  
                           DECLARE @CAMINHO NVARCHAR(MAX);  
                           DECLARE @COMANDO NVARCHAR(MAX);  
                           DECLARE @Parametro NVARCHAR(max);  
                           DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(MAX);  
                           DECLARE @CODEXT VARCHAR(17);  
                           DECLARE @TIPO_GRAVACAO_FOTO INTEGER;  
                       SELECT @TIPO_GRAVACAO_FOTO = NOMEARQUIVOWEBCAM,  
                               @PATH = COALESCE(PATH_FOTO_ALT, PATH_FOTO)  
                           FROM CONFIG WITH(NOLOCK)   
                           SET @Parametro = N'@fotoParametro varbinary(max) output';  
                       IF (@TipoPessoa = 1)  
                           BEGIN  
                               SELECT @FILE = NOME,  
                                       @CODIGO = CODIGO,  
                                       @CODEXT = CODEXT,  
                                       @nome_usuario = NOME   
                                   FROM FISICA WITH(NOLOCK)   
                               WHERE CODIGO = @Codigo  
                           IF (@TIPO_GRAVACAO_FOTO = 1)  
                           BEGIN  
                               SET @FILE = @CODEXT;  
                           END;             
                               SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(@FILE, ' ', '_'),'\',''),'/',''),':',''),  
                                               '*',''),'?',''),'>',''),'<',''),'|',''),'"',''),'.',''),'''','') + '_' +   
                                               CAST(@CODIGO AS VARCHAR) + '.JPG';         
                       END  
                       ELSE IF (@TipoPessoa = 2)  
                       BEGIN  
                               SELECT @FILE = PAI_NOME,  
                                       @CODIGO = FA.CODIGO   
                                   FROM FAMILIAS FA WITH(NOLOCK)  
                               INNER JOIN DADOSPF D WITH(NOLOCK)  
                                   ON D.FAMILIA = FA.CODIGO             
                               WHERE D.FAMILIA = @Codigo  
                               SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(@FILE, ' ', '_'),'\',''),'/',''),':',''),  
                                               '*',''),'?',''),'>',''),'<',''),'|',''),'"',''),'.',''),'''','') + '_' +   
                                               CAST(@CODIGO AS VARCHAR) + '_pai.JPG';           
                       END  
                       ELSE IF (@TipoPessoa = 3)  
                       begin  
                               SELECT @FILE = MAE_NOME,  
                                       @CODIGO = FA.CODIGO    
                                   FROM FAMILIAS FA WITH(NOLOCK)  
                               INNER JOIN DADOSPF D WITH(NOLOCK)  
                                   ON D.FAMILIA = FA.CODIGO             
                               WHERE D.FAMILIA = @Codigo  
                               SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(@FILE, ' ', '_'),'\',''),'/',''),':',''),  
                               '*',''),'?',''),'>',''),'<',''),'|',''),'"',''),'.',''),'''','') + '_' +   
                                               CAST(@CODIGO AS VARCHAR) + '_mae.JPG';   
                       END  
                                           SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'É','E'),'È','E'),'Ê','E');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Í','I'),'Ì','I'),'Î','I');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Á','A'),'À','A'),'Â','A'),'Ã','A');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ó','O'),'Ò','O'),'Ô','O'),'Õ','O');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ú','U'),'Ù','U'),'Û','U');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ý','Y'),'`Y','Y');                                   
                                           SET @FILE = REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ç','C');  
                                           set @CAMINHO = @PATH + '\' + @FILE;  
                         print @CAMINHO;  
                           SET @COMANDO = N'SELECT @fotoParametro = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N' + '''' + @CAMINHO + '''' + ' , SINGLE_BLOB) Load'  
                           BEGIN TRY  
                               EXEC sp_executesql @COMANDO, @Parametro, @fotoParametro = @foto OUTPUT;  
                           END TRY  
                           BEGIN CATCH  
                               set @foto = NULL  
                           END CATCH  
                           if ((@foto is null) and (@TipoPessoa = 1))  
                           begin  
                               if (@TIPO_GRAVACAO_FOTO = 1)  
                               begin  
                               SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(@NOME_USUARIO, ' ', '_'),'\',''),'/',''),':',''),  
                                               '*',''),'?',''),'>',''),'<',''),'|',''),'"',''),'.',''),'''','') + '_' +   
                                               CAST(@CODIGO AS VARCHAR) + '.JPG';   
                               end  
                               else  
                               begin  
                               SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(  
                                               REPLACE(@CODEXT, ' ', '_'),'\',''),'/',''),':',''),  
                                               '*',''),'?',''),'>',''),'<',''),'|',''),'"',''),'.',''),'''','') + '_' +   
                                               CAST(@CODIGO AS VARCHAR) + '.JPG';             
                               end  
                                               SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'É','E'),'È','E'),'Ê','E');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Í','I'),'Ì','I'),'Î','I');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Á','A'),'À','A'),'Â','A'),'Ã','A');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ó','O'),'Ò','O'),'Ô','O'),'Õ','O');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ú','U'),'Ù','U'),'Û','U');  
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ý','Y'),'`Y','Y');        
                                       SET @FILE = REPLACE(@FILE, 'Ç','C');         
                               set @CAMINHO = @PATH + '\' + @FILE;  
                               SET @COMANDO = N'SELECT @fotoParametro = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N' + '''' + @CAMINHO + '''' + ' , SINGLE_BLOB) Load'  
                               BEGIN TRY  
                                       EXEC sp_executesql @COMANDO, @Parametro, @fotoParametro = @foto OUTPUT;  
                               END TRY  
                               BEGIN CATCH  
                                       set @foto = NULL  
                               END CATCH  
                           end  
                   end
```

Não consegui retornar em lote, por se tratar de uma Procedure. Mas consegui retornar se o Cadastro possuí foto ou não através do report do sistema, em tela.